# Simple undo and redo button with Draftjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rich-text-editor, draftjs

i am trying to get a simple undo and redo button working to start off with. So far i have tried reading through the documentation on the draftjs website but it feels quite cryptic and there are no examples of what i am trying to do.

Here is what i have attempted so far, on click of the undo it does nothing. Not sure what i am missing. Thanks in advance.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Editor, EditorState} from 'draft-js';

class MyEditor extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {editorState: EditorState.createEmpty()};
    this.onChange = (editorState) => this.setState({editorState});
  }

  onClick() {
    this.setState({
      editorState: EditorState.undo(editorState)
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <button onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>undo</button>
        <Editor editorState={this.state.editorState} onChange={this.onChange} />
        </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyEditor />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already found out why (you needed to reference the editorState variable correctly), but I still want to give you this on the way:

You should change your `onClick` method as followed:

```
onClick() {
  this.setState({
    editorState: EditorState.undo(editorState)
  })
}
```

to

```
onClick() {
  this.onChange(EditorState.undo(this.state.editorState));
}
```

For DraftJS, it is usually "bad practise" if you try to change the editorState via a method other than `onChange`.

If you do any change to the editorState, just trigger `onChange` once you're done.

Also, do you know Draft JS Plugins already? It's a wonderful collection of very useful plugins for DraftJS also including undo/redo buttons!

https://www.draft-js-plugins.com/

Comment: Hi @simon, i dont understand the refactor you made, could you provide an example using the code i posted above? I will then gladly accept as the answer. Also i know about draftjs plugins thanks :), but i have a separate menu to utilise in another react container.

Comment: I update my answer to make it more clear, I hope it helps!

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Check how I use the onChange method in my edited answer. You need to directly pass the changed editorState as an argument to onChange, not pass in an object like in setstate()

Comment: Yes sorry, just saw

Comment: Perfect, thanks Simon. Also updated my own fix/answer with your recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

This is the fix, i needed to reference the editorstate correctly like so, then i refactored based on Simon's answer:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Editor, EditorState} from 'draft-js';

class MyEditor extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {editorState: EditorState.createEmpty()};
    this.onChange = (editorState) => this.setState({editorState});
  }

  onUndo() {
    this.onChange(EditorState.undo(this.state.editorState));
  }

  onRedo() {
    this.onChange(EditorState.redo(this.state.editorState));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <button onClick={this.onUndo.bind(this)}>undo</button>
      <button onClick={this.onRedo.bind(this)}>Redo</button>
        <Editor editorState={this.state.editorState} onChange={this.onChange} />
        </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyEditor />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: I'm surprised that this works.  Don't you find that the Editor state changes when it loses focus (since the focus has moved to the button) and so the undo is just operating on the focus change?  I've found this only works if you use onMouseDown and called event.preventDefault()

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use the Undo/Redo plugin provided by the draft team

[check it out please](https://www.draft-js-plugins.com/plugin/undo)